# singleton in PHP behaves abnormally

Tags: php, singleton

I am trying to implement a singleton in PHP, but for some reason everytime the static variable "$instances" is null and it get's reinitialized.

```
  class Enteliprint_Model_EnteliService {

        public static $instances;

        static public function getSingltoneInstances() {                  DebugBreak(); 
            if (NULL == Enteliprint_Model_EnteliService::$instances) {
                $result = array();          
                foreach (Enteliprint_Model_EnteliPrint::getEnteliPrintInstances(True) as $instance) {   
                    $associatedSceddules = json_decode($instance['AssocSchedules']);
                    $scheduleIDs = '-1,';                    
                    foreach ($associatedSceddules as $key=>$schedule) {
                        $scheduleIDs = $scheduleIDs.($key > 0 ? ', ' : '').$schedule->ID;
                    }                  
                    $instance['AssocFilters'] = Enteliprint_Model_EnteliFilter::getEnteliFilternstances($scheduleIDs);
                    $result[] = $instance;
                }
                Enteliprint_Model_EnteliService::$instances = $result;
            }
            return Enteliprint_Model_EnteliService::$instances;
        }

        public static function sendEvents($events) {                                  
            $instances = Enteliprint_Model_EnteliService::getSingltoneInstances();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: check what is inside foreach loop. Inside same class, use self:: instead of class name

Comment: An empty array equals null. Debug what the contents of $result is after the foreach loop.

Comment: inside the for each loop the debug suggests the values are retrieved normally, used also self:: but there are no any changes